# The vue data does not refresh in the webpage

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am new to JavaScript. Recently I am using the webpack + vuejs to create a SPA as my server.

I have made the following Hello.vue,

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg1 }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ msg2 }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ msg3 }}</h1>
    <button @click='createDevice'>Create a new device
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
var count = 1
export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data: () => {
    return {
      msg1: 'I am Stephen',
      msg2: 'Hello',
      msg3: '0'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createDevice: () => {
      count += 1
      this.msg3 = count.toString()
      console.log(this.msg3)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But I find that the msg3 on the webpage is not updated, but I could monitor "this.msg3" is increasing in the development console.

Anyone could help?

Thank you very much!

Stephen Lau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying in https://jsfiddle.net, I find that the shorthand "() => " could not be used.
After changing the "() =>" back to "function ()", the text binding works.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg1 }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ msg2 }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ msg3 }}</h1>
    <button @click='createDevice'>Create a new device
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
var count = 1
export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data: function () {
    return {
      msg1: 'I am Stephen',
      msg2: 'Hello',
      msg3: '0'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createDevice: function () {
      count += 1
      this.msg3 = count.toString()
      console.log(this.msg3)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Thank you very much.